# How to populate an array from size (equal to user input) with random unique numbers? CLOJURE

Tags: java, algorithm, intellij-idea, clojure, bubble-sort

currently programming the bubblesort algorithm.
I found the source code of someone of the web:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the size of the array which you would like to create: ");
```

What the application now does, it that it takes the input number of the user. And makes an array of random numbers. Using this array, it applies the Bubblesort algorithm.

Now, I am trying to translate this to Clojure.
I know that the user input can be achieved by the functions:

```
Flush
```

and

```
read-line
```

Apart from that, I don't understand how to get the user-input for required array size, then create an array of random numbers, and then applying bubble sort.
So far, this is what I have (Bubblesort found from rosetta website.):

```
 (ns BubbleSort
  (:import java.util.ArrayList)
  (:import (java.util Date)))

(defn safe-println [& more]
  (.write *out* (str (clojure.string/join " " more) "\n")))


; set a timestamp
(defn restart-profiling []
  (def last-time-stamp (atom (System/nanoTime))
    )
  )

; get ms since last timestamp
(defn get-delta-ms []
  (let [last @last-time-stamp
        current (System/nanoTime)
        ticks (- current last)
        ]

    (restart-profiling)
    (float (/ ticks 1000000)) ; calculate the delta in milliseconds
    )
  )


(defn bubble-sort
  "Sort in-place.
  arr must implement the Java List interface and should support
  random access, e.g. an ArrayList."
  ([arr] (bubble-sort compare arr))
  ([cmp arr]
   (letfn [(swap! [i j]
             (let [t (.get arr i)]
               (doto arr
                 (.set i (.get arr j))
                 (.set j t))))
           (sorter [stop-i]
             (let [changed (atom false)]
               (doseq [i (range stop-i)]
                 (if (pos? (cmp (.get arr i) (.get arr (inc i))))
                   (do
                     (swap! i (inc i))
                     (reset! changed true))))
               @changed))]
     (doseq [stop-i (range (dec (.size arr)) -1 -1)
             :while (sorter stop-i)])
     arr)))

(restart-profiling)
(println (bubble-sort (ArrayList. [10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
                                   10 9 8 7 6


                                   ])))

(safe-println "The serial implementation "(get-delta-ms) "ms")
```

Needed:

- user-input
- creating an array of random number of user-input size

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

User-input:

```
    def(input
      (println "Enter the size of the array: ")
    )
    println(read-line)
```

the input should determine the size of the array.

Remaining part:

Populate array with unique random numbers of the size represented by input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read the input with `read-line`, you can parse it into an integer with `read-string`, then use `rand` to generate random numbers. After that, convert them to a Java array using `to-array`. The below function will prompt the user for an array size and return an array of random numbers from 0 to 1:

```
(defn random-array-prompt []
  (print "Enter array size:")
  (let [n (read-string (read-line))]
    (to-array (repeatedly n rand))))
```

After that, can call that function in the repl:

```
(println (seq (bubble-sort (random-array-prompt))))
```

This will prompt you for the size and print the sorted sequence.

Comment: Thank you for yout comment. I am quite new to clojure, perhaps I am not understanding it right, but this does not work? Any tips?

Comment: Could you please be more specific - do you receive any error message, etc.?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: EOF while reading,

thats the error message that i receive..

Comment: My fault, there was a missing bracket (and def instead of defn) in my snippet. Corrected it and added some explanation - please look at the answer.

Comment: Also, if you are learning Clojure while having a Java background, it may make sense for you to start with a general introduction to Clojure, like this: http://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/ and then learn about using Java arrays and integration with Java.

Comment: thankk you :) , couldn't find a proper website where they explained from start... Let me see if ur code works :D

Comment: Do i need to merge your code with my random unique def, or copy it and keep the bubble sort algorithm in the middel? Look like it is not working.. too many agruments in def

Comment: True, it is with the defn :) you said you correced it, therefore, i copied it later on. but now it is doing nothing :O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134612/discussion-between-aleph-aleph-and-lilienfa).